# Adding voltage from multiple voltage dividers

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, dac, adder

[image]
I have the following schematic set up, where all of the resistances are known (I just didn't add them to the schematic as they should be irrelevant). If I read the voltage across the ground and the middle connection between each set of resistors, I should get a divided value for my voltage. I want to take the sum of these divided voltages. How would one do this?

I'm trying to take an 8-bit input signal and convert that to an analog output voltage, if that helps. These voltage dividers should sum to the input voltage (9v) when all are switched on.

Comment: There is no question about the thing you want to do. Please ask an answerable question. Also how do you expect to sum the voltages, with an opamp?

Comment: Put a schematic of what you have so far into the question. What behaviour do you want the final solution to have, that simply connecting all the outputs of these resistive dividers together would not have? Without that, and the schematic, nobody could guess what you want.

Comment: @Neil_UK, done. Is this more helpful? Sorry, this is my first time on this forum.

Comment: The most straight forward way would be to first buffer each voltage with a unit amplifier, then pass it to a [summing amplifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html). Or use an ADC with some digital logic.

Comment: OTOH it looks like an XY-problem, while the X one most likely has a better solution.

Comment: What else would you need to know to fully understand the X problem @EugeneSh. ?

Comment: What this thing is for. Which application it is supposed to serve.

Comment: I added that very answer at the bottom of the post, @EugeneSh.

Comment: So you are trying to build a DAC. You could have searched for that, there are a lot of material out there. For instance https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linear_integrated_circuits_applications/linear_integrated_circuits_applications_digital_to_analog_converters.htm

Comment: You want a D/A converter. Google that. Plenty of good results I hope. Best choice probably would be a [R-2R architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder). Simpler than a bunch of voltage dividers with oddball resistor ratios. Just one resistor value is all you need. Get more resistors than needed (way more), so that you can select a narrow tolerance batch for the most significant few bits. You'll want to measure the resistors to 3-digit accuracy, so most likely a 4.5 digit multimeter is needed.

Comment: Contrary to your statement that the actual reaistance values don't matter may not be true. If some divider has ohms range values and another divider has kilo-ohms or megaohms, they require quite different handling. But that's not a good approach for a DAC anyway, so the question how to add them together may not make sense as that's a different problem from how to make a DAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a weighted sum of ones and zeros, something like

$$ V_{OUT} = W_1V_1 + W_2V_2 \cdots W_8V_8 $$

where \$V_n\$ is either +9V or 0V, and \$W_n\$ is some fractional "weight" that multiplies its corresponding \$V_n\$ prior to the final addition.

Before I continue, please consider an R-2R ladder network of resistors, which you can read about in [this article](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/combination/r-2r-dac.html), and which may satisfy your requirements without any active circuitry.

If the weights are in the ratio \$2^0:2^1:2^2:\cdots :2^7\$, then what you are building is a regular digital to analogue converter (DAC), and the solution may be just to use a ready-made 8-bit DAC IC. There seems to be a resurgence lately, of people using the good old [DAC0808](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac0808.pdf), so check that out. There are many, many other devices, some easy to use, some not so much, being more "configurable", or having special features.

Otherwise, near the bottom of this answer I'll shown you how to obtain this behaviour with a single op-amp and only 9 resistors. However, if you insist on doing this using the system you showed us, consisting of pairs of resistors to obtain each \$W_nV_n\$, then you must consider that each individual pair's output must not be loaded in any way, since drawing current from them will upset their potential. This means you must first buffer each output with a voltage follower:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT8Z8l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This module must be repeated 8 times, one for each "bit". Then you may connect whatever you like (within reason) to \$V_n\$, without affecting the potential there.

The additions can be performed accurately using the classic summing amplifier, in the red box below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8N6qI.png)</sup>

The array of resistors at each input, should be repeated for each bit. I've shown only three, you will need eight. This gives you:

$$ V_{OUT1} = -(V_1 + V_2 \cdots + V_n) $$

Note the negative sign. This requires that OA1 be powered from a negative supply. If you require a positive sum, then you must invert the signal using the second stage in the blue box. This gets you:

$$ V_{OUT2} = -V_{OUT1} = V_1 + V_2 \cdots + V_n $$

Including all the buffers I described before, that's a lot of op-amps (10), and a lot of resistors (I'm not going to count them), for something that could be done using a lot less. If you are able to use an alternative to the system you showed us, then a solution be as simple as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr0yUL.png)</sup>

With that circuit (nothing more), you have:

$$ V_{OUT} = -R_f\left( \frac{V_1}{R_{W1}} + \frac{V_2}{R_{W2}} + \cdots + \frac{V_8}{R_{W8}} \right) $$

\$V_n\$ is +9V with the corresponding switch closed, and 0V when it's open. You can see the correlation with the weighted sum expression at the top of this answer. You would have to choose \$R_{Wn}\$ for each input such that each weight \$W_n\$ corresponds to \$\frac{R_F}{R_{Wn}}\$.

Again the negative sign is present, so you may need to invert the output as we did before, with the system in the blue box. Also, the op-amps will of course require a negative supply.

Be careful with the op-amps you use. Many are *unable* to produce outputs close to the supply potentials. The inputs also have similar constraints, regarding what potential you may apply to them. Your best bet is to use so-called "rail-to-rail output" devices. Consult the op-amp datasheet to find out what you can and can't do or expect.